# Marking up a price range Schema.org

Tags: data-structures, schema.org, microdata

So i have fully marked up my product pages with structured data. We are a little stuck with a few of our pages. We have price ranges on some of the product pages like:

£2.99 - £7.99

How can we go about setting this up, we have managed to do set priced products using the below code

```
<span itemprop="priceCurrency" >£</span>
<span itemprop="price" >44.00</span>
```

If anyone can help with this that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's `minPrice`/`maxPrice` on http://schema.org/PriceSpecification.

Comment: @Caramiriel: Don’t you want to create an answer? :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with schema's, I just want to nudge where to look :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use two properties of [PriceSpecification](https://schema.org/PriceSpecification), [minPrice](https://schema.org/minPrice) and [maxPrice](https://schema.org/maxPrice). Google requires the price property too hence I included the price as the minPrice in the snippet below.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="name">Offer Name</span>
    <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <span itemprop="name">Product Name</span>
        <span itemprop="description">Product Description</span>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
        £<span itemprop="price minPrice">5.49</span>–
        £<span itemprop="maxPrice">7.99</span>
        (<span itemprop="priceCurrency">GBP</span>)
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using JSON-LD:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Offer",
    "name": "",
    "itemOffered": {
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "",
        "description": ""
    },
    "priceSpecification": {
        "@type": "PriceSpecification",
        "price": "4.99",
        "minPrice": "2.99",
        "maxPrice": "7.99",
        "priceCurrency": "GBP"
    }
}
</script>
```

@unor may wish to show a version using microdata.